# Trouble on receiving image at an GCP App Engine service running a Flask service

Tags: android, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I'm developing an app by enables the user to take a photo and send it to a Keras model for prediction. This model is already deployed in a Google App Engine Service with a Python script that uses Flask for receiving via POST request the image and calling the model to make the prediction. Here's the Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import flask
import io
import logging
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.applications import imagenet_utils
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image


# initialize our Flask application and the Keras model
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True
model = None

def recortar(image):
    # Function that centers and crop image. Please, asume that it works properly. Return is a numpy array.
    return image

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    model = load_model('modelo_1.h5')
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    data = {"success": False}

    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        if flask.request.files.get("image"):
            # read the image in PIL format
            image = flask.request.files["image"].read()
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image))

            image = recortar(image)
            app.logger.info('Tamaño: '+str(image.size))
            image = img_to_array(image)
            image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

            with graph.as_default():
                preds = model.predict(image)

            data['predictions'] = str(np.squeeze(preds).tolist())

            data["success"] = True  
            return flask.jsonify(data)
        else:
            return "No se ha obtenido la imagen"
    else:
        return "El HTTP request no era POST"

# if this is the main thread of execution first load the model and
# then start the server
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(("* Loading Keras model and Flask starting server..."
        "please wait until server has fully started"))
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Sending the image via curl works perfectly: as expected, I obtain a JSON response from the server containing the prediction. Here's the CURL command and the server response:

```
>> curl -X POST -F image=@nevus.jpg 'https://example.com/predict'
{"predictions":"[0.7404708862304688, 0.25952914357185364]","success":true}
```

Then I try to repeat the same process, but through an Android app, but I get a 500 error as response. When checking the logs on Stackdriver Error Reporting, I see the following stacktrace:AttributeError:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'
at predict (/home/vmagent/app/main.py:73)
at dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1799)
at full_dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1813)
at reraise (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:35)
at handle_user_exception (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1718)
at full_dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1815)
at wsgi_app (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:2292)
at reraise (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:35)
at handle_exception (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1741)
at wsgi_app (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:2295)
at __call__ (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:2309)
at handle_request (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py:176)
at handle (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py:135)
```

This error refers to image object, so I assume that, as the code was working properly before, the error must be in the way I send the image through the HTTP request. Recall that the image is taken when a user click a button, because this button sends an intent for taking the photo. When the photo is taken, the user can click a send button, whose code I post bellow. Note that orientedBitmap corresponds to the photo taken in bitmap format.

```
btn_enviarfoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Botón \"enviar\" pulsado. Codificando imagen.");
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                orientedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                orientedBitmap.recycle();
                uploadToServer(byteArray);
            }
        });
```

uploadToServer just calls the execute methong of AsynchTask class as shown bellow:

```
private void uploadToServer(byte[] data) {
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        Log.d(TAG, "Imagen codificada. Enviando al servidor.");
        ObtenerPrediccionTask task = new ObtenerPrediccionTask();
        task.execute(bitmapOrg);    
    }
```

And finally and most important, this is the code for the ObtenerPrediccionTask class:

```
public class ObtenerPrediccionTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... imagen) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        String probabilidad_melanoma = "";
        JsonReader jsonReader = null;


        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < imagen.length; i++) {
                Bitmap imagen2 = imagen[i];
                imagen2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
                byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                InputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(ba);


                URL url = new URL("https://example.com/predict"); // not the real URL

                String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                String twoHyphens = "--";
                String boundary = "xxxxxxxx";
                String str = twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd;


                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Allow Inputs & Outputs
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);

                // Enable POST method
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
                        "image" + "\";filename=\"" +
                        "foto.jpg" + "\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, 1024);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // Read file
                int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, 1024);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                connection.getResponseMessage();

                fileInputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    InputStream responseStream = new
                            BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

                    BufferedReader responseStreamReader =
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));

                    String line = "";
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    responseStreamReader.close();

                    String response = stringBuilder.toString();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Imagen recibida por el servidor y pasada al modelo. Esta es la respuesta: " + response);

                    jsonReader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(response));
                    probabilidad_melanoma = readJson(jsonReader);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(responseCode));
                }
            }
            return probabilidad_melanoma;
        } catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {
            Log.e(TAG, malformedURLException.toString());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException io) {
            Log.e(TAG, io.toString());
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String probabilidad_melanoma) {
        if (probabilidad_melanoma != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Probabilidad melanoma: " + probabilidad_melanoma);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "La respuesta ha sido nula");
        }
    }
}
```

readJson function is also working properly, so don't get bothered by it.

This last chunk of code is the result of an extensive search in SO of a way to properly send an image, but as nothing has worked yet, I've run out of ideas. What's the problem with my code?

Comment: Before you fix this problem, use this opportunity to add error checking to your code. Your code needs to handle errors and be prepared for clients breaking, being hacked, connection failures, etc. Never allow your server side code to crash for any reason.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'll take your suggestion into account. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash traceback indicates that at this line `image` is `None`:

```
        app.logger.info('Tamaño: '+str(image.size))
```

Which means that `recortar()` returns `None`, despite your comments:

```
# Function that centers and crop image. Please, asume that it works properly. Return is a numpy array.
```

So your `the error must be in the way I send the image through the HTTP request` assumption *might* be wrong. Before spending time on that I'd first add checks to ensure that `recortar()` works properly.

Comment: Finally I solved it like three months ago, and that was exactly de problem. Thank you for your answer!